# Stripe Flutter: Get transaction id after successful payment

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

We have implemented stripe payment in flutter and everything works perfectly. We are now interested in getting the transaction ID generated as a result of a successful payment.

We have tried going through the documentation but could not get the method that will give us the payment transaction ID.

Can someone please help us with the method?

Answer (score 3):

- **Hi guys,**

  You can get txn id and other details regarding to the payment from an
  API provided by **Stripe**,

  1. Create your **createPaymentIntent** first

  ```
  paymentIntent = await createPaymentIntent(context: context);
  ```

  2. get a **paymentIntentId** from the paymentIntent

  ```
  var paymentIntentId = paymentIntent!['id'];
  ```

  3. Create another function to retrieve the payment detials need to pass secretKey on headers and payment intent as param

     ```
     retrieveTxnId(
       {required BuildContext context, required String paymentIntent}) async {
     try {

       http.Response response = await http.get(
           Uri.parse(
               'https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges?payment_intent=$paymentIntent'),
           headers: {
             "Authorization": "Bearer $secretKey",
             "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
           });

       if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          var data =json.decode(response.body);
         log("Transaction Id ${data['data'][0]['balanceTransaction']}");
       }
     } catch (e) {
       throw Exception(e.toString());
     }
     ```

     }

  You can get the transaction id by using this method, I hope this help
  you: **Ameen :)**

Answer (score 0):

The transactionId is the PaymentIntent[1] or SetupIntent[2] ID, depending on your integration.

When accepting payments using Stripe, you are probably creating a **PaymentIntent** in your flow.

For example, and according to this Flutter Example [3], here is how to track PaymentIntent during your payment flow:

1. Create a PaymentIntent in your backend [4]
2. Pass the paymentIntent ID to you flutter App like passing here the client_secret [5]

You should use this ID in all of your Payment flow integration in order to track it.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-id

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents/object#setup_intent_object-id

[3] https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/blob/main/example

[4] https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/blob/main/example/server/src/index.ts#L544

[5] https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/blob/main/example/lib/screens/payment_sheet/payment_sheet_screen.dart#L91